# Convert kinetic energy of a bullet into electricity and store it in a super-capacitor

Tags: energy, electricity, capacitance

I was thinking about bulletproof materials, they have to be so thick and heavy because they try to hold all of the kinetic energy of a bullet and then dissipate it (right?)
So what if you made a thin and light-weight material that can convert that kinetic energy into electricity and try to hold it for re-use in super-capacitors? Would that be possible? Or maybe just emit that energy in another way, like, light?

Answer (score 2):

What is your goal - to stop bullets or to generate electricity?

The key to stopping bullets is not so much to absorb the energy (although that matters too) but to absorb the *momentum*. You may know that

$$p = F\Delta t$$

In other words, given a certain momentum $mv=p$, you need to apply a force F for a time $\Delta t$ in order to slow it down. The thicker your bullet proof vest, the longer the time (large $\Delta t$ = smaller $F$.)

Also, bulle proof vests attempt to spread the force over a large area, so that the peak pressure you experience (which will cause bruising or worse) will be reduced.

Note that you just want to stop the bullet - you don't want to bounce it back, because to do so you would have to apply more force. This is why a vest made of strong springs is not a great idea - also, the bullets might ricochet and hit you or someone else again.

Here is a [nice picture of a bullet](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/SM_Walley/publication/222663687_The_contribution_of_the_Cavendish_Laboratory_to_the_understanding_of_solid_particle_erosion_mechanisms/links/00b7d51ae3b3990204000000.pdf) that had hit an alumina tile in a certain kind of armor (impact was from the top!): the characteristic cone shaped crack forms a pyramid that spreads the load, and adding some Kevlar mesh and padding between that and the body provides an effective armor.

[image]

Note that the "energy absorbing" aspect is what stops the bullet from bouncing off you - but the mechanism for spreading the load is ultimately how body armor saves lives. Energy absorption is often achieved by having the material crack a lot - a lot of energy is needed to create all those new surfaces. It does make that kind of armor single use.

There are some attempts to make materials that are "liquid until you hit them" - a bit like silly putty. This class of materials has the interesting property that the molecules can flow past one another at slow strain rates - but if strain rate is high, they interlock. It's like trying to untie a piece of string - if you are patient you can do it, but if you pull too hard you make a horrible knot. This kind of material is called STF (Shear Thickening Fluid), a non-Newtonian fluid. See for example [this article](http://www.reuters.com/article/2015/04/02/us-poland-ballistic-liquid-idUSKBN0MT20D20150402) for a demonstration. They state clearly in the article that the real goal is to reduce the deflection at the back of the armor - this means you have to spread the load of the force. They also mention (as I did above) that you want to avoid ricochet - which means you do need to absorb the energy, not just bounce the bullet.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are all way over-thinking the issue. There is a trivial material that can slow a bullet down without being damaged at all. Think water. A couple feet of a water shield will do exactly what you need to stop a bullet enough to make it basically harmless with a bit of additional bullet-proofing. Most of the bullet's kinetic energy will stay in the water and can be extracted (at least partially) from the hydrostatic shockwave. Now... is it practical? No. Being shot at is not a good way of supplying oneself with energy.

Answer (score 0):

Your material has to absorb the kinetic energy before converting it into other forms. A thin, lightweight panel would be unable to absorb the bullet's kinetic energy before it punched a hole in the panel and continued on it's way. Plot the tensile strength of the material against the impact energy of the bullet.

Unobtainium, impossibrium, phlebotinum and related alloys might work, but deflector shields will be lighter.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation about why I am wrong. I didn't realized the need to absorb before conventing. But I don't see how the joke can help...

Answer (score -1):

I think it is possible to produce equipment converting kinetic energy from a bullet. We could use a string attached to a generator and a spring. The string then turns the generator and thereby produces electricity but it is to hard to to something that does not get damaged from the bullet. Here we can use momentum. If it is supplied to create thick but empty are for slowing down bullet with a certain time:
p=mv

V is the bullets velocity and m is the mass of bullet and the material we used for covering material then we have a certain energy that we can produce energy.

Comment: This answer is near impossible to parse. I tried my best, but I really don't understand the last two sentences. Maybe you can reread and improve yourself? Then, it might be a valid answer!

Answer (score -4):

There is no physical challenge (at first glance). This is a technological issue. Man just didn't developed technology to do this (and they are not trying).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: It does, it says it is not possible to do what he asked because the current technology didn't went so far. How is that not provide an answer? I don't have any intention to critique or request any clarification. The question is clear enough and the answer is "no" and the reason of no is the lack of technology. It is not theorically impossible to do that.

Comment: @Mandrill then you're not saying it's impossible, you're saying it is possible but hasn't been achieved yet, without giving any _reasons_ as to why that may be the case or what the challenges are, or even addressing the assumption about how bullet-proof materials work.